# What is the definition of an "involved party" as used by the International Humanitarian Fact-Finding Commission?

Tags: international

[A page](http://www.ihffc.org/index.asp?page=procedure) on the website of the International Humanitarian Fact-Finding Commission (IHFFC) states

> One of the most important characteristics of the Commission is that it may conduct an investigation only with the consent of the parties involved.

Let's say that Country A recognizes the IHFFC and asks it to investigate a conflict between Country A and Country B, which has also recognized the IHFFC and declared so accordingly.

If any other parties are involved, they must give their consent to any investigation. However, what is the definition of "involved"? If Country C lent arms to Country B that were used in the action under investigation, is it counted as "involved", or would it have to take direct military action for it to be considered "involved"?

Answer (score 1):

Parties means parties to the conflict.

The circumstances of providing weapons to one of the belligerents would not make you a party, providing intelligence, targeting or advice might.

Worth noting that in nearly 25 years of existence the commission has *never* conducted an investigation. Possibly because of an inability to get the required consent.

Comment: I fully acknowledge the lack of pretty much anything to go on here, but doesn't this just shift the question to defining what it means to be a party to the conflict? Or is the answer simply that there's no clear definition available (a possibility I've considered)?

Comment: Since the commission is a child of the Geneva Convention, the definition probably flows from there.